# Observe the state of a Worker withou LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

So, I am using workmanager to retrieve data from an FTP server. I have to display one type or information or another type deppending on the state of the worker.

I was using getWorkInfoByIdLiveData on the viewmodel and I was observing the state of the worker on the activity. But, as the Observer is almost deprecated I am trying to use Flow instead.

The problem that I have is that I don't know why, I can't use the asStateFlow() on the livedata. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79OVt.jpg)

Does anyone know a way to observe the state of a worker without using LiveData and Observer?

Thank youuu

Comment: I don't find any `Flow` info in the `WorkManager` documentation.

Comment: I don't think that's the way you transform a LiveData to StateFlow. May this can help you:
https://chao2zhang.medium.com/converting-livedata-to-flow-lessons-learned-9362a00611c8

Comment: From the docs, it looks very much like `LiveData` is what you should be using to observe `WorkManager` state. I can't see anything saying that `LiveData.observe` is being deprecated any time soon. Where are you seeing information saying that it will be deprecated?

Comment: @Sam https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer here. Anyway I was able to find a solution. I used the   ".asFlow" extension to convert the livedata to a Flow. Now everything work fine, even in API 33 :)

Comment: @writer_chris Thank you very much. I was having the problem that I didn't have my dependencies updated, so the extension ".asFlow" wasn't appearing. But now everything is working as expected. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the LiveData-ktx dependency to your build.gradle:

`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1`

Then you can convert LiveData to Kotlin Coroutine's Flow.

```
val operation = WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(myRequest)
operation.state.asFlow()
```